# Should logic be put in underlying SQL query or in google data studio?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

In my past, using engine report like Crystal Report, SSRS and others, the best practice was to give the data to the report engine and have it crunch the numbers and logics. Usually, logics were aggregation, pivot table and sometime some basic mathematic and `if` statements.

Today, with BigQuery and DataStudio, I'm told the opposite on the premise that bigquery will be more performant computing the aggregation.

So, does the old best practice still stand or does putting computations in the underlying bigquery statement is really the way to go with the combo "BigQuery and DataStudio"?

Comment: It really depends, and this is certainly an opinion question. I prefer to keep all business logic away from the BI/Visualization layer if possible.  You are using DataStudio now, but what happens if your company switches to Tableau or Looker?  You have to re-do all that work.  But, if your logic is at a lower level, then the switch becomes much easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Today, with BigQuery and DataStudio, I'm told the opposite on the
> premise that bigquery will be more performant computing the
> aggregation.

Data Studio and BigQuery use the same engine to compute aggregations, so performance is not a factor.
You should decide whether to put calculations into SQL or into DataStudio formulas based on other factors such as maintenance, access control etc.